# java how to extend a class while implement parent method

Tags: java, inheritance

I have `class A`, and `class B` inherit `class A`, and `class C` inherit `class B`,

and all of the classes have this method:

```
public void someMethod();
```

How can i call this method from `class C` so the method from `class A` would be implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

You can call the implementation from the parent:

```
super.someMethod();
```

But that's all. If B defines an implementation, that's the one that will get called. If not, A will get called, but you can't force A to be called (bypassing B).

The reason is that because C inherits from B, it's up to the implementation in B whether or not the implementation in A is used. There may be a very good reason why the implementation in A should *not* be used.

If you want C to use A's implementation, inherit directly from A. If you need some code from B, consider [delegating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_%28programming%29) to an instance of B.

Answer (score 2):

Any class can only access instance of its immediate parent using `super`. You can not access grandparent.

Which means in `C`'s member function you can invoke `super.someMethod()`. This will invoke, `B`'s `someMethod()` implementation. However, any given object does not have access to instance of its grandparent.

Hence you can not invoke `A.someMethod()` implementation from `C`.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of design, you can declare `someMethod()` `final` in class A, then all three have it, but cannot change the implementation. Then have a second method which does the second thing needed in B.

Or for a more complex situation, some refactoring idea like this may also help: http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/formTemplateMethod.html